# clearing unused tables from Deltalake

Tags: azure-databricks, parquet, delta-lake

I am trying to cleanup tables(delta, views, parquet and external) from deltalake.

1. I am first trying to findout username who has accessed the tables.
2. describe history command is only working for delta tables.

How can i find users who have created or used "parquet", "views" and "external" tables in databricks? or any better way to cleanup databricks data?

Comment: Could you please the error if you followed any approach?

Comment: Regarding the Cleaning up data are you trying to perform some transformation on the table?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Yes, i am actually using "describe history table name" command to fetch user associated with it.But it is only applicable for delta tables.Looking ways for views, external tables, parquet. And also any best practice to cleanup the data from storage account perspective also

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is Parquet tables in Databricks do not maintain an explicit history of user activity.

And also similar to Parquet tables, external tables do not have built-in history tracking.

Here is the way you can track users using the log audit tables in databricks

For example I have

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

schema=StructType([StructField("emp_Id",IntegerType(),True), StructField("name",StringType(),True),StructField("city",StringType(),True),StructField("country",StringType(),True),StructField("Contact_no",IntegerType(),True)])


data = [(2000,"kevin","New York","USA",4567888),(3000,"david","dallas","USA",545789),(4000,"peter","coloumbs","USA",123456789),(5000,"Rosy","coloumbs","USA",98989788)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
df.display()
```

[image]

[image]

I have created a delta table which is the target location:

```
%sql
Create Or Replace TABLE dim_employee
(emp_Id INT,
name STRING,
City String,
Country String,
Contact_no INT
)
Using DELTA
LOCATION "/FileStore/Tables/delta_merge"
```

[image]

Creating a dataframe for the source:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("Source_view")
```

[image]

Using the `Merge` statement to (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) the source and target.

```
%sql
MERGE INTO dim_employee AS target
USING Source_view AS source
ON target.emp_Id = source.emp_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    target.name = source.name,
    target.city = source.city,
    target.country = source.country,
    target.Contact_no = source.Contact_no
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (emp_id, name, city, country, contact_no)
  VALUES (emp_id, name, city, country, contact_no)
```

[image]

Now creating an audit log table:

```
%sql
Create Table Audit_logs
                        (operation string,
                        updated_time timestamp,
                        user_name string,
                        notebook_name string,
                        numTargetRowsUpdated int,
                        numTargetRowsInserted int,
                        numTargetRowsDeleted int)
```

Create dataframe with lastoperation in delta table:

```
from delta.tables import * 
delta.df= DeltaTable.forPath(spark,"/FileStore/Tables/delta_merge" )
lastOperationDF= delta.df.history()
```

The above statement get the last operation
display(lastOperationDF):

[image]

Leveraging the `OperationParametres` column for inserting the values into `Audit_table`. `OperationParameters` is string we will have to use the explode to flatten the value

Explode Df:

```
explode_DF =lastOperationDF.select(lastOperationDF.operation,explode(lastOperationDF.operationMetrics))

    explode_DF_select = explode_DF.select(explode_DF.operation, explode_DF.key, explode_DF.value.cast('int'))
 display(explode_DF_select)
```

[image]

Pivot operation to convert rows into columns:

```
pivot_df = explode_DF_select.groupBy("operation").pivot("key").sum("value")
display(pivot_df)
```

[image]

Select only columns needed for log audit tables:

```
pivot_df_select=pivot_df.select(pivot_df.operation,pivot_df.numTargetRowsMatchedUpdated,pivot_df.numTargetRowsInserted,pivot_df.
numTargetRowsDeleted)
display(pivot_df_select)
```

[image]

Adding notebook parameters such as username, notepath etc.:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, current_timestamp

audit_df = pivot_df_select.withColumn("user_name", lit(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().userName().get())) \
                         .withColumn("notebook_name", lit(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().get())) \
                         .withColumn("Updated_time", lit(current_timestamp()))
display(audit_df)
```

[image]

Rearranging the columns similar to audit table in SQL:

```
audit_df_select = audit_df.select(audit_df.operation,audit_df.Updated_time,audit_df.user_name,audit_df.numTargetRowsMatchedUpdated,audit_df.numTargetRowsInserted,audit_df.numTargetRowsDeleted)
display(audit_df_select)
```

[image]

Create temp view on dataframe:

```
audit_df_select.createOrReplaceTempView("Audit")
```

[image]

Inserting the rows from `Audit` into `Audit_logs`:

[image]

[image]

Regarding the better way to cleanup databricks data is

Handle missing values, Remove duplicates, Convert data types,
Filter and transform data.

These above data transformation should help you better in cleaning the data in databricks.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Here you have showcase for "delta" table only, which we can do using "describe history table name".Can you suggest how to clean up other files from delta lake?

Comment: @SaswatRay
You can try this command

%python
from delta.tables import *

# Vacuum a Delta table to remove old files
DeltaTable.forPath(spark, '/FileStore/Tables/delta_merge').vacuum()